# Read uncommitted using Firebird FIBPlus components

Tags: delphi, firebird, fibplus

Using a `TpFIBTransaction` component, I'm trying to start a [READ UNCOMMITTED](https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/isql-transactions.html) transaction.

First of all, the `TPBMode` property has 3 possible values:

- tpbDefault
- tpbReadCommitted
- tpbRepeatableRead

In `TpFIBTransaction.StartTransaction` I saw that setting `tpbReadCommitted` forces the following parameters:

- write
- isc_tpb_nowait
- read_committed
- rec_version

Using `tpbRepeatableRead` forces the following parameters instead:

- write
- isc_tpb_nowait
- concurrency

So, it seems the only way to have "custom" transaction parameters is to set the `tpbDefault` value.

The values allowed for the `TrParams` property are the following (from fib.pas unit)

```
  TPBConstantNames: array[1..isc_tpb_last_tpb_constant] of String = (
    'consistency',
    'concurrency',
    'shared',
    'protected',
    'exclusive',
    'wait',
    'nowait',
    'read',
    'write',
    'lock_read',
    'lock_write',
    'verb_time',
    'commit_time',
    'ignore_limbo',
    'read_committed',
    'autocommit',
    'rec_version',
    'no_rec_version',
    'restart_requests',
    'no_auto_undo',
    'no_savepoint'
  );
```

I've tried adding the 'read' value only, but it seems it's still unable to read uncommitted data, even if there's not 'read_committed' in `TrParams` property.

```
MyTransaction.TrParams.Clear();
MyTransaction.TrParams.Add('read');
```

Is there some missing value in `TPBConstantNames` (Something like 'read_uncommitted', if it exists...), or is there another way to setup a Firebird "read uncommitted" transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible because Firebird does not support read uncomitted isolation level.

You can find the following information in the documentation [documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-transacs.html#fblangref30-transacs-settransac):

> Note
> The READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level is a synonym for READ
> COMMITTED, and provided only for syntax compatibility. It provides the
> exact same semantics as READ COMMITTED, and does not allow you to view
> uncommitted changes of other transactions.

and:

> The three isolation levels supported in Firebird are:
>
> SNAPSHOT
>
> SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY
>
> READ COMMITTED with two specifications (NO RECORD_VERSION and
> RECORD_VERSION)

Comment: Note that since Firebird 4.0, `READ COMMITTED` has three specifications (the third is `READ CONSISTENCY`), and by default, this new third option will be used even if `RECORD_VERSION` or `NO RECORD_VERSION` is specified. This can be changed using the `ReadConsistency` setting in firebird.conf (global) or in databases.conf (per-database)